# When using ytdl_player in discord.py, and i am trying to queue another song, i get this error. How do i fix this?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot, and in this bot I am including a command that plays music, I also have a command to queue songs. When I am playing a song, and I try to queue another, I get the error message below, this is my code for the queue command.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from chat import *

players = {}
queues = {}

def check_queue(id):
    if queues[id] != []:
        player = queues[id].pop(0)
        players[id] = player
        player.start()

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def play(self, ctx):

        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
        url = ctx.message.content
        abc = url[5:]
        server = ctx.message.server
        if self.bot.voice_client_in(server):
            await self.bot.say("queued")
            pass

        else:
            await self.bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
        server = ctx.message.server
        voice_client = self.bot.voice_client_in(server)

        player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(abc, ytdl_options={'default_search': 'auto'}, before_options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 " "-reconnect_delay_max 5", after=lambda: check_queue(server.id))

        players[server.id] = player
        await self.bot.say("now playing" + abc)
        player.start()
```

Expected result: It works, and the song queues to be played next.
actual result: av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
               av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
               Error writing trailer of pipe:1: Invalid argument
               Error writing trailer of pipe:1: Broken pipe

```
           Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: hi, welcome to SO. It seems that you have an issue with talking to your command line tool (as your PIPE is broken). Is everything installed correctly? Are you able to run minimal examples from tutorials?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have recently changed `queues = {}` into `queues = []`, and that seemed to fix the broken PIPE, but now, both songs play at the same time. Do you know why that is? I have a feeling it has something to do with `check_queue`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if self.bot.voice_client_in(server):
            await self.q(ctx, abc)

async def q(self, ctx, url):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = self.bot.voice_client_in(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, ytdl_options={'default_search': 'auto'}, after=lambda: check_queue(server.id))

    if server.id in queues:
        queues[server.id].append(player)
    else:
        queues[server.id] = [player]
    await self.bot.say("queued")
```

I just made a new function called `q()`, which added next song to queue in a better way than before, changed `queues = []` back into `queues = {}` aswell